# Книги по написанию драйверов под Windows

Tags: windows, драйвер, c, c++, ассемблер

Доброго времени суток. Задался я тут целью написать драйвер под Windows, да и вообще разобраться с этим, поэтому прошу у Вас помощи. Подскажите статьи, книги по написанию драйверов под Windows. Сразу оговорюсь я подхожу к этому серьезно, поэтому готов перелопатить кучу материала, который хоть как то связан с данной темой. Наверное, мне понадобиться знание asm и С++ (С я неплохо знаю). Поэтому прошу так же посоветовать дельные книги по asm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Начните с скачивания WinDDK и изучения сэмплов, идущих в поставке. Их довольно-таки много и они неплохо задокументированы. Это даст хороший толчок для старта, ну а дальше — MSDN, — содержит более чем исчерпывающую документацию по вопросам разработки драйверов.

Часть вызовов недокументированна и относится к Private API, но использовать их, тем не менее, приходится  часто. В этом случае вам понадобятся .dbg файлы соответствующих библиотек для извлечения информации о смещениях в структурах.

Comment: а может Вы еще и книжку какую для начала посоветуете ?

Comment: Нет, не посоветую, поскольку не знаю их достойных по этой теме. Впрочем, не особо то и интересовался, так что, возможно и ошибаюсь. Сам же шёл по пути, описанному выше (сэмплы из DDK + MSDN), особых затруднений не возникло.

Comment: Есть книга Солдатова, но она не очень хорошая, как по мне.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что вам может пригодиться следующее:

Почитать:

1. Уолтер Они. "Использование Microsoft Windows Driver Model"
2. Марк Руссинович, Дэвид Соломон. "Внутреннее устройство Microsoft Windows"
3. "Everything Windows Driver Development". http://www.osronline.com/
4. Блог: http://redplait.blogspot.ru/
5. Блог: http://sww-it.ru/

Для разработки:

1. WinDBG -> Virtual KD -> VmWare Workstation с Windows
2. Настроенная переменная **_nt_symbol_path**
3. Возможно пригодится pykd. Модуль к Windbg для автомазации на Python
4. Исходники некоторых частей Windows, опытные знают где и что взять. Здесь приводить не имеет смысла

Рекомендации:

1. Читайте MSDN
2. Если плохо понимаете в MSDN читайте в книгах, но предпочитайте англоязычные
3. Не читайте книги Солдатова
4. Не пытайтесь использовать SoftICE. Он замечателен, но умер. Остался убогий, но всегда актуальный Windbg.

Answer (score 2):

Из классики вспоминается, например
Walter Oney - Programming the Microsoft Windows Driver Model (Уолтер Они - Использование Microsoft Windows Driver Model)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно пока только "потренироваться на кошечках", то можно попробовать использовать NuMega DriverStudio - [статейка](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/visualc/wdmnumega/), для написания простейших драйверов и получения представления, она подойдет, хоть и уже малость устарела. А если серьезно драйверами заниматься - то да, - WinDDK.